# Failed to Connect at new Port in MySQL

Tags: mysql, connection, port, mysql-workbench

Using MySQL WorkBench, on creating a New Connection, and changing port to 3307 which is unoccupied, with new username and password, i am getting this error after Testing connection using right username and password:

[image]

Comment: You are attempting to use Workbench to change the port used by the MySQL server? That's not how it works. Workbench simply connects to your existing MySQL server so have the connection use the port it uses.

Comment: @PhilipOlson I created a new Connection using Workbench, but this is not working. What is thee solution then?

Comment: Please explain "changing port to 3307 which is unoccupied", namely the unoccupied part. I think I'm misreading the question.

Comment: @PhilipOlson I have a question, is it possible to change Host name from `localhost` to something else?

Comment: Yeah, right-click on the connection, choose "edit connection", and then modify the "Hostname" field. Just to be clear, Workbench does not create any of this (username, password, port, ...) it simply uses currently existing ones. Maybe that's the confusion. You must have your MySQL server already set up and going. Using the MySQL Installer is the easiest way to install/upgrade/configure the MySQL server on Windows. http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/